# How to convert an account_name to a string?

Tags: smart-contract, account-name

I need to be able to convert a name/account_name to a string for some processing in my smart contract. I have found and used the `string_to_name` function for converting in the other direction, but cannot find an equivalent to the `name_to_string` function. I saw a reference to `name` having a `to_string()` method, but the compiler disagreed with its existence and threw errors.

What function is available to perform this conversion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the name struct. 'name' is defined in types.hpp.

For example, if you have the variable user of type account_name, you can print the user as follows:

```
auto n = name{user};
print("Hello, ", n);

std::string str = n.to_string();
```

Comment: I tried this, and was told by the compiler that `name` didn't have a `to_string` method on it.

Comment: Discovered that the source code for the `type.hpp` file that was being included was out of date.  Updated to the most recent version of the header and things work now.